# ReactJs : What is the proper way of accessing the state data in the root component where the link between React and Redux has been implemented?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

**DISCLAIMER:** This error has been mentioned on stackoverflow before but my case is different.
I have had a problem with the user login which I have explained in this [stackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213080/reactjs-problem-with-displaying-home-page-after-user-logs-in). I invite you to go and quickly take a look.
So as I mentioned in that question in my root file I have this:

> App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const authLinks = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          name="Login Page"
          render={props => <Login {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/404"
          name="Page 404"
          render={props => <Page404 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/500"
          name="Page 500"
          render={props => <Page500 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/home"
          name="Home"
          render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    );
 
    const guestLinks = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          name="Login Page"
          render={props => <Login {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact 
          path="/register"
          name="Register Page"
          render={props => <Register {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/404"
          name="Page 404"
          render={props => <Page404 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/500"
          name="Page 500"
          render={props => <Page500 {...props} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    );

    const currentState = store.getState();
    console.log(
      "currentState.auth.isAuthenticated: ",
      currentState.auth.isAuthenticated
    );
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            {console.log(currentState.auth.isAuthenticated)}
            {/* TODO: Not sure if this always works. If after the user logsin he gets a blank page and he has to reload to be redirected to home then
            this way of routing may need to modified */}
            {currentState.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
          </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I have been told that I am accessing the state **isAuthenticated** incorrectly:

```
 {currentState.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
```

That I should access it by using **connect()**. That was actually the first thing I have tried. It didn't work. But, I took their advice and tried it again:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const authLinks = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          name="Login Page"
          render={props => <Login {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/404"
          name="Page 404"
          render={props => <Page404 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/500"
          name="Page 500"
          render={props => <Page500 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/home"
          name="Home"
          render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    );

    const guestLinks = (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          name="Login Page"
          render={props => <Login {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/register"
          name="Register Page"
          render={props => <Register {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/404"
          name="Page 404"
          render={props => <Page404 {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/500"
          name="Page 500"
          render={props => <Page500 {...props} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    );

    const currentState = store.getState();
    console.log(
      "currentState.auth.isAuthenticated: ",
      currentState.auth.isAuthenticated
    );
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            {console.log(currentState.auth.isAuthenticated)}
            {/* TODO: Not sure if this always works. If after the user logsin he gets a blank page and he has to reload to be redirected to home then
            this way of routing may need to modified */}
            {/* {currentState.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks} */}
            {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
          </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(withRouter(App));
```

which gives the error I've mentioned:

```
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter(App))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(withRouter(App)) in connect options.
```

which kind of makes sense, since the store is passed **root component** App.js through the router. So the state of the app shouldn't be accessed in the same way it is accessed in **childComponents** through **connect**.
So I have two questions:
**QUESTION 1:** Why am I getting this error?
**QUESTION 2:** What is the right way of accessing the state data inside the root component where the link between the redux and react is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

QUESTION 1:

I believe you have to wrap `withRouter` first.

Try this:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App));
```

QUESTION 2:
You are mapping the state to props so the correct way to access `auth` from your state in your component is `this.props.auth`

Try to console.log(this.props) in your render and you will see what I mean. Also check the docs on https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Hope this helps

Comment: For QUESTION 1 ; Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Connect(App)) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: For QUESTION 2 : I know that but the problem is that I cannot use connect with the root component where the link between the store and the app has been setup.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the withRouter at all. try just `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App)`

Comment: It still gives the same error. I guess I just have to find a way to make it work with this:             {currentState.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
like in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER 1**:
I think that you should use "connect" on a component called inside Provider.
The [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/troubleshooting#could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props) says:

```
Could not find "store" in either the context or props
If you have context issues,

Make sure you don’t have a duplicate instance of React on the page.
Make sure you didn’t forget to wrap your root or some other ancestor component in <Provider>.
Make sure you’re running the latest versions of React and React Redux.
```

```js
/*Into App.js*/
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            <ConnectedComponent>
          </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
    
    /*ConnectedComponent.js*/
    class ConnectedComponent extends React
    {
      render(){
      {
        /* move all your routing and app code Here*/
      }
    }
    
    //call connect on your ConnectedComponent
    export connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ConnectedComponent)
```

I also think that you don't need to use withRouter because seems that you don't need the ReactRouter props (match, history, location) on your App component.

You can see here wen you should use *withRouter*: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

**ANSWER 2**:
The connect() function do the job of connecting the Redux store to your React components tree. You should always access to the store data through the props object.

Comment: The problem is that I am accessing the store state data inside the root component App where the store has been linked to the whole app. So this is different from accessing the state inside child components.

Comment: If you call **connect** in a child component instead of your App component you don't need to call `const currentState = store.getState();` to get the value of **isAuthenticated**. You can just call `this.props.auth.isAuthenticated`.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: I am trying to access state in the root component. And they told me I should use connect to do so.

Comment: If you want to access to the store in the root component you can just call `store.getState()`. the connect function must be called on a component rendered as a children of the `<Provider>` component. Note that if you want to use react-redux lib to link the Redux store to your React App, accessing directly to the store is not a best practice.